# Get dvb_hdhomerun to work with debian

Tags: module, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Im trying to get a Silicon Dust network DVB receiver to work with my debian machine.

My debian is running:

```
uname -a:
Linux myMachine 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
Release:        7.1
Codename:       wheezy
```

I've tried a lot, but my latest attempt is the following

```
apt-get source linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64
# I got a folder named linux-3.2.46
cd linux-3.2.46
# vim Makefile, changed SUBLEVEL to 0, and EXTRAVERSION to '-4-amd64'
cp /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64 .config
make oldconfig
cp /usr/src/linux-3.2.46/Module.symvers .
make prepare scripts
cd ../dvb_hdhomerun-0.0.15/kernel
vim Makefile, changed KERNEL_DIR to the linux-3.2.46 dir.
make # works fine
make install # works fine.
```

I can build the module, but when I try to load it with modprobe I get the following error

```
ERROR: could not insert 'dvb_hdhomerun': Exec format error
```

dmesg says

```
[252722.865357] dvb_hdhomerun_core: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

modinfo dvb_hdhomerun says:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/extra/dvb_hdhomerun.ko
version:        0.0.15
license:        GPL
description:    HDHomeRun Driver
author:         Villy Thomsen
version:        0.0.15
license:        GPL
description:    HDHomeRun driver
author:         Villy Thomsen
version:        0.0.15
license:        GPL
description:    HDHomeRun Driver Core Module
author:         Villy Thomsen
srcversion:     94B767B76E32F22F26FE6A2
depends:        dvb-core,dvb_hdhomerun_core
vermagic:       3.2.0-4-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           adapter_nr:DVB adapter numbers (array of short)
```

modinfo dvb_hdhomerun_core says:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/extra/dvb_hdhomerun_core.ko
version:        0.0.15
license:        GPL
description:    HDHomeRun Driver Core Module
author:         Villy Thomsen
srcversion:     B9DACADA733D0C535EAC3E3
depends:
vermagic:       3.2.0-4-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           hdhomerun_debug_mask:Mask for debug output
 (int)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a script at https://sourceforge.net/p/dvbhdhomerun/discussion/1223414/thread/a0772136/ that kind of solved my problem.

what I did was

```
apt-get install linux-source-3.2
unpacked the tar.bz2 file
used that dir as KERNEL_DIR in dvbhdhomerun-0.0.15/kernel/Makefile
used /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build/.config as .config file in linux-source-3.2 dir.
used /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build/Module.symvers as Module.symvers file in linux-source-3.2 dir.
make KERNEL_VERSION=3.2.0-4-amd64 when compiling the module
```

And that seems to work:)

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer does indeed work.  It's not ideal because you end up with:

- unmanaged software
- poor init scripts
- no systemd support
- no kernel upgrade support

Since I was re-installing my home server I decided to work on fixing the dkms dpkg mess.

https://github.com/h0tw1r3/dvbhdhomerun

Repo has the source for building debian packages that fix the aforementioned issues.

Like the original author - I don't supply binary packages, but it's pretty easy to create them.  Just follow the first two sections of [debian maintainers build guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html).